# Croogo Translate and Menu plugins

Tags: plugins, menu, translate, croogo

everybody.

I use CakePHP in all my projects for years, but it's my first time using Croogo.
I have two problems here (both related to Translate plugin) and I'll really appreciate any help.

First, I added the Contacts plugin to the Translate bootstrap configuration, as indicated in http://wiki.croogo.org/1.4/developers/core-plugins/translate (I'm using Croogo 1.5, but unfortunately there is no wiki documentation for this version yet), in order to translate the Contact forms. I've created two contact forms in my system: one called Contact (alias contact), and it's linked to a Menu plugin link using the Link address: `/plugin:contacts/controller:contacts/action:view/contact`and the other one is called Work With Us (alias work-with-us), and it's linked to a Menu plugin link using the link address: `/plugin:contacts/controller:contacts/action:view/work-with-us`
The problem is when I access my system using a locale url indication, say `http://localhost/por`, the Menu link for Contact is `http://localhost/por/contact` what is good, but the Menu link for the another contact form is `http://localhost/contacts/contacts/view/work-with-us/locale:por`  what is not good, since when the user clicks on this link the whole website turns to another language, because the URL is not formatted as expected.

Second problem: I created a plugin called Orders. And I added one controller's action to the Menu plugin link as: `plugin:orders/controller:orders/action:add`  but, again, when I access the system, say `http://localhost/por`, the link for the "Add order" is not formatted properly: `http://localhost/orders/orders/add/locale:por`

I would really appreciate any help. Probably, I'm doing something wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (although I didn't like it). I used the router configuration to get a root url address:

```
// Work with us
CroogoRouter::connect('/work-with-us', array(
    'plugin' => 'contacts', 'controller' => 'contacts', 'action' => 'view', 'work-with-us'
));
```

The, the Menu plugin link put the locale indicator in the right place.
Thanks, anyways!